# Matlab Split an image to 8x8 2D array and save it in another array

Tags: arrays, matlab

Below is my code , i was only able to save the last array of the image ( the 88 position ) . I know the error is at line w11 but no matter how i try i cant seem to make w11 a 3D array . Help please ?

```
Ie=imread('Untitled-1.014.jpg');  % size 256x160
len = 256/8 ;
wid = 160/8 ;

for m = 1:8
    x1(m) = (len*m);
end

for n = 1:8
    y1(n)= (wid*n);
end

for m = 1:8
    x2(m)= (len*m)-len+1;
end

for n = 1:8
    y2(n)= (wid*n)-wid+1;
end

for m = 1:8
    for n=1:8
        w11 = Ie(x2(m):x1(m),y2(n):y1(n));
    end
end
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Next time take the time to properly format your code for readability. Also, I've removed some blank lines. Please check I haven't messed anything up

Comment: I'm very confused with your problem description.  What exactly do you want accomplish?  Your code isn't really clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you want to split full 2D image in small 8x8 blocks and save all these blocks in 3D array. To do so `w11`  must be 3D from the beginning and you have sub-assign elements:

```
% The image (replaced with random data)
height = 256;
width = 160;        
Ie = rand(height, width);

% Preallocation of smaller 8x8 blocks in 3D
blocksize = 8;
nw = width / blocksize;
nh = height / blocksize;
blockCount = nw*nh;
blocks = zeros(blocksize, blocksize, blockCount);

% Splitting image
index = 1;
sub = (1:blocksize);    
for wi = 1: nw,

    wsub =  sub + (wi-1)*blocksize; % sub indices along width

    for hi = 1: nh,

        hsub = sub + (hi-1)*blocksize; % sub indices along height

        blocks(:, :, index) = Ie(hsub, wsub); % subset assignement
        index = index + 1;

    end
end
```

You can then access smaller block like this:

```
block = blocks(:,:,5); % The 5th block (of size 8x8)
```

*NB: I put block index as last dimension in order to automatically squeeze trailing singleton dimension (this avoids calling [squeeze](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html) all the time.*